# How to install R packages in VS code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, reshape2

I have installed R in vscode and all its extensions.
I tried installing packages through vscode terminal.But after successfull installation when  run the code it says no package called "reshape2"(i used `library("reshape2")`) to import the library.

Comment: What directory did you install to and what directory is VS code looking in?

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine or a desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to install in command prompt and then try to install in vs code editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command in your terminal,

```
install.packages(x) library(x)
```

NB: Replace x with your library name

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command in your terminal,

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" --vanilla -e  "install.packages('reshape2', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

Note: With the path of your R executable