# Cannot find R function in VS Code

Tags: r

I'm using VS code and I am trying to learn the ggplot2 package in R. I installed ggplot2 in the base R console and then from the VS Code editor, as per this post's suggestion: [How to install R packages in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66075525/how-to-install-r-packages-in-vs-code)

```
install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

I then downloaded an external dataset to use it to learn ggplot2:

```
load(url('https://github.com/matloff/fasteR/blob/master/data/mlb.RData?raw=true'))
```

Then I tried to assign the output of ggplot2, on the mlb dataset, to a variable:

```
p <- ggplot2(mlb)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in ggplot2(mlb) : could not find function "ggplot2"
```

This is happening with other packages as well. For reference, my current directory is:
"/Users/saunok/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Areas_of_Responsibility/Programming/R"

The installed packages are being installed in:
"/var/folders/hq/lbddkgmd0fbbp1r2lqsp7nkm0000gn/T//RtmpYA5gLR/downloaded_packages"

I tried: To use installed R packages in VS Code
I expected: To be able to use the package for analysis
Result: R or VS Code is failing to detect the installed packages.

Comment: After installing the package, you'll need to load it `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: Also, the function for a plot is `ggplot()`, not `ggplot2()`

Comment: Thank you - ggplot did the trick. I was following a tutorial where it was ggplot2, and I didn't understand. But the path where ggplot2 was installed - the one given in the post - is different from the path I get from `libPaths()`. Is this the norm?